# Joomla default tooltip is hiding

Tags: joomla, tooltip

I am using Joomla version 3.0

I have used default Joomla tootip to display image on hover in tooltip content.
But the problem is it is getting hidden below the navigation bar.

Refer link: http://books.kisan.co.in

Can anyone tell me any setting/changes we need to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tooltips look fine for me. Which browser are you seeing this issue in? And why on earth are all your metas, scripts and css files ALL being imported in the body tag? They should be in the head tag

Comment: I am browsing in Mozilla Firefox (version 28.0). It is present on Chrome too. When we scroll page the tooltip hides behind the navigation bar, it should scroll down too.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have set z-index:1000 on the div-element with class djcf on the bottom of the page. This is the tooltip-box. Hovever, the navigation-element on top of the page has a z-index=1030. So increase your z-index on the djcf-element to more than 1030, and you should be OK, regards JOnas